# Jquery show or hide children link if it is available

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question on Jquery. If I click on Link1, which does not have any `ul.children` and the class current_page_item will be added(not shown in this code as it will be added automatically by Wordpress), then `ul.children` in Link2 should be hidden.

If i click on Link 2, which will have both class `page_item_has_children current_page_item`, in this case `ul.children` should be shown. I have tried my code bellow, which is i know it is absolutely wrong. Please give me your advices. Many thanks.

```js
if($(.navigation).hasClass(page_item_has_children)){
  (.navigation .page_item_has_children .children).hide();
}else if( $(.navigation).hasClass(page_item_has_children) && $(.navigation).hasClass(current_page_item)){
  (.navigation .page_item_has_children .children).show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="navigation">
<li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
<li class="page_item_has_children current_page_item"><a href="#">Link2</a>
  <ul class="children">
 <li class="page_item"><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
 <li class="page_item "><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: First thing, in all of your javascript selectors, you need some kind of quote marks around the selector names. Second thing, inside each of your if statements, you don't use $() to select the nav elements. Little things trip us up...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am learning Jquery and java so I still do have glue about it. Do you have any good source to learn Jquery with exercise? I have googled it but if you have please share.

Comment: Sitepoint has quite a few good books, check out their 'novice to ninja' series. Really, though, I was one of the original beta testers for jQuery, attended the first jQueryCon in Cambridge, still have the t-shirt! Comes down to practice practice practice...

Comment: Thank you. I am checking it :)

Comment: Updated this to include localStorage, but stackoverflow has security blocks in place for accessing localStorage. So it's also up as a fiddle. Best!

Answer (score 0):

How about simply hiding all nested UL elements, then simply showing the children of the clicked one?

```js
$(".navigation li").each(function() {
  // When we first load, hide all nested menus.
    $(this).children("ul").hide();
  if (localStorage.menuNumber) {
    $(".navigation li").eq(localStorage.menuNumber).children().show();
    }
  })
  .on("click", function() {
  // When any top-level ul is clicked, hide the
  //  nested menus then show the current one.
    $(this).parent().children().find("ul").hide();
    $(this).children().show();
  // We also want to persist this selection,
  //  should the user refresh...
  localStorage.menuNumber = $(this).index;
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="navigation">
  <li><a href="#">Link1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="page_item_has_children current_page_item"><a href="#">Link2</a>
    <ul class="children">
      <li class="page_item"><a href="#">Link3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="page_item "><a href="#">Link4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Edited it so that when it initially loads, all nested uls are hidden. Hope this helps! And edited again, to store the clicked menu in local storage. Sadly, for security reasons, this won't work here. See it as a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/snowMonkey/fnuvvLwb/

Comment: How to edit your code to get it work bette? As if I am in Link1 and I press refresh browser ```u.children``` will show, so I have to click on Link1 again to get ```u.children``` be hidden.

Comment: Thank you. It works now, but if I am in Link2 and refresh browser, ```u.children``` is hidden until i click again on Link2

Comment: And it will be. Refresh clears all evidence of anything. Sort of the point of refresh, page data doesn't usually persist. If you want to do this, it would take something like localStorage -- basically, you'd store a cookie indicating which menu item had been clicked, and then read that back in after the refresh.

Comment: See it working here: https://snowmonkey.000webhostapp.com/menuThing.html# -- This version uses localStorage to save the index of the clicked li within its parent ul, and if there IS a value, it'll restore the state as it was.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a bit more towards your scenario (edited based on comment):

```js
$(".navigation li").on("click", function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("page_item_has_children") && $(this).hasClass("current_page_item")) {
    $(".navigation .children").show();
  } else {
    $(".navigation .children").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="navigation">
  <li><a href="#">Link1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="page_item_has_children current_page_item links"><a href="#">Link2</a>
    <ul class="children">
      <li class="page_item"><a href="#">Link3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="page_item "><a href="#">Link4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Link1 does not have ```page_item_has_children``` class on it ```li```, as this class is added automatically by Wordpress when there is ```ul.children```